# show selected option in dropdown javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I have implemented the nav bar and how to show the selected options first using javascript

```js
function getoptions(){
  var x =document.getElementById("languagelist");  
  var y = document.getElementById("language");  
  y.innerHTML= // set the selected language
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button id="language" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                English
        </button>
        <div id="languagelist" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" onclick="getoptions()">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/en">English</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/fr">French</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you used bootstrap for drop down?

Comment: @Jinesh, thanks fr reply and yes, when i select french, button name should be `French`, need to do only in Javascript

Comment: I think you need to implement in jquery because dropdown create his own function in the jquery

Comment: @Senthil please see my answer which is pure `javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **This pure javascript solution would work for you. run and test**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="language" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="clickButton()">
        English
      </button>
      <div id="languagelist" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" onclick="clickItem(); return false">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/en">English</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/fr">French</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

<script>

  function clickButton() {
    document.getElementById("languagelist").click();
  }

  function clickItem() {
    var element = document.getElementById("languagelist");
    for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
      (function(index) {
        element.children[i].onclick = function() {
          var thetext = element.getElementsByTagName('a')[index].innerHTML;
          // var thehref = element.getElementsByTagName('a')[index].href; get the href here once you hosted, for testing I will use the name
          var buttonelement = document.getElementById("language");
          buttonelement.innerText = thetext;
          window.open("/"+thetext);
        }
      })(i);
    }
  }

</script>

</html>
```

hope this will help to someone. cheers!

Comment: thanks a lot ,it works, but if have href links, `<a class="dropdown-item" href="/en">English</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="/fr">French</a>` if selected french updates the dropdown and its does not change the url,

Comment: do you want to navigate or just change the url by appending `en` or `fr`

Comment: thanks for reply,navigate it and dropdown should not change, click on `french` should show /fr in url and dropdown should be french

Comment: you cannot navigate when you are in the same page while dropdown text change in javascript. page will reload once you get back. only way is to open it in a new tab. see my updated answer. user your browser to test. open in new tab won't work in code snippets

Comment: thanks for reply, when i click dropdown , should i make ajax call for not to reload the page but content change and dropdown text change to happen,

Comment: when i click on dropdown , is it possible to change url in all pages, like default will be /en, /en/contact for every page, when i select french, how to change all url to /fr, fr/contact for every page

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('value'));

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add data attribute and identify the element,

```
<nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button id="language" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            English
        </button>
        <div id="languagelist" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2"  >
            <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="/en"  href="/en">English</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="/fr"  href="/fr">French</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

script like this,

remove element and add as first item

```
 $(".dropdown-item").click(function () {
           var value = $(this).data('value');
           var innerHtmlValue = $(this).html();
           $('.dropdown-item').filter('[data-value="' + value + '"]').remove();
           $('#languagelist a:eq(0)').before("<a class='dropdown-item' data-value='" + value + "' href='/en'>" + innerHtmlValue + "</a>");
       });
```